# android show other elements at the end of a recyclerview

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am currently programming a small android task app!

Now I have a problem, I completly implemented a RecyclerView to show my tasks but now I want to add a button at the end of the RecyclerView that shows done tasks.

So you scroll trough all tasks then at the end there is a button. If you click the button another RecyclerView opens with the tasks that are already done.

Spent a lot of time researching about this, hope anybody here can help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a lot of different view types in recyclerview viewholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006180/how-to-handle-a-lot-of-different-view-types-in-recyclerview-viewholder)

Answer (score 1):

You might actually be better off using an action in the toolbar. This is because the user should not have to scroll to the bottom of the list to filter the done tasks. Taking it further, you could expand the action to show a drop down for different types for filters, but I'm not a fan of drop downs in the toolbar. If you're not using a toolbar, try using a floating button at the bottom right.

Comment: A filter button in the toolbar could also show a filter dialog